# Android Java Display website in app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have a web page appear in my app. This is what I have done:

In my Manifest I added the following code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In my content_main.xml I added the following code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In my main Activity.java file added the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String url = "http://bigdaddyapp.com";

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        //next line explained below
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

But I get the following errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You havent defined the 'webview' variable, e.g. using `private WebView webview`. Your webview's layout ID is not myWebView it's webView. And finally, you should use `WebChromeClient` instead of `MyWebViewClient` (which appears to be never defined)

Comment: webView 'W' is capital you used small

Answer (score 4):

You have quite a few issues here.

First, you never declare your `webView` variable.
In this case, the fix is simple. You just need to define its type inline:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
```

Second, you gave your WebView the ID "webView" in your layout XML, but you try to refer to it via `R.id.myWebView`. Switch this to use the same ID and it will work.

For the third error, it sounds like you don't actually have a class called `MyWebViewClient`. Make sure that you do and that it is public.

You also aren't setting the correct layout. You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, but your layout is called "content_main."

The rest of the errors should disappear once you fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
```